# Basecamp - Get Attachments - Page 2 of results

Tags: basecamp

I am trying to return all the attachments in a project using the basecamp api call documented here:

https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/attachments.md

The Basecamp documentation says that you can do this in this way...

```
https://basecamp.com/1234567/api/v1/projects/1234567/attachments.json
```

Which will return the top 50 results. And which is does :)

But, I have more than 50 results.

So, the documentation says:

> We will return 50 attachments per page. If the result set has 50 attachments, it's your responsibility to check the next page to see if there are any more attachments -- you do this by adding  &page=2  to the query, then  &page=3  and so on.

So, I have tried:

```
https://basecamp.com/1234567/api/v1/projects/1234567/attachments.json&page=2
```

But when I try this I get an error:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type - Only application/json requests are accepted. Check out 'No XML, just JSON' on https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api
```

Am I reading the instructions wrong? Sure that call should work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies.

I should have spotted it... the documentation says "&" when it should say "?"

The call should be

```
https://basecamp.com/1234567/api/v1/projects/1234567/attachments.json?page=2
```